# How to get price items of bundle product in order API-REST Magento 2.3?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3, bundled-product

How to get the **price** of items of **bundle product** in **order**?

[image]

Comment: There is an Admin REST API endpoint for getting all children of a bundle product using the parents sku.
Check the documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#tag/bundle-productsproductSkuchildren

Comment: @HelgeB Tks. 
But I need the price of the bundle item for the order, because if I change the price, I will not have the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
```

foreach ( $orderItems as $item ) {
    $customOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
    $itemOptions = $customOptions['bundle_options']
    echo '';print_r($itemOptions); // In this array, you can get the price of the selected option of the bundle product.
}